# O que pode fazer a textura sumir no OpenGL?

Tags: c, golang, opengl

Estou usando uma engine chama [Engo](https://github.com/EngoEngine/engo), e fiz um fork e estou adicionando algumas coisas e, ao mesmo tempo, tentando aprender mais sobre o OpenGL.

Como é um questão gráfico há como colocar uma imagem do que está ocorrendo:

[image: grid]

Todas as imagens que criam o quadriculado são iguais, e todas usam a mesma textura enviada ao OpenGL, apenas rotaciono e defino a posição:

> [image: tile]

*É uma pequena borda, de 8 pixels, a imagem é 128x128 pixels no total.*

---

Como podem perceber algumas das "grades" ficam menores ou maiores, e dependendo até somem por completo.

Isso parece estar sendo causado pelo `TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`, já que ele é o responsável por determinar o que deve ser feito quando a imagem precisa ser encolhida.

Vi que existem vários tipos de `TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`, desde `GL_LINEAR` e `GL_NEAREST` e também outros que exigem o *MipMap*, com o `NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST`.

Para fazer funcionar esses parâmetros que precisam do MipMap é preciso criar o  *MipMap*, para isso eu utilizei o `GenerateMipmap` logo após o `TexImage2D`, desta forma:

```
gl.TexImage2D(uint32(target), int32(level), int32(internalFormat), int32(width), int32(height), int32(0), uint32(format), uint32(kind), gl.Ptr(pix))
gl.GenerateMipmap(uint32(target))
```

De todas as formas, o problema ainda persiste, e na verdade ele pode piorar. Quando utiliza o MipMap ele se torna cinza:

[image: gray]

Além disso, usar qualquer filtro `LINEAR` (seja o que precisa do MipMap ou não), ele adiciona uma pequena borda com opacidade distinta:

[image: border]

*Eu ampliei esta imagem no PhotoShop para ter certeza de que existia uma borda, e ela está aí*.

Lembre-se que a imagem é transparente por dentro e a borda é toda de uma mesma opacidade, não haveria motivos para criar uma borda, se há queria saber qual seria o  motivo. E este comportamento não acontece no `NEAREST`.

---

O VertexShader usado é:

```
attribute vec2 in_Position;
attribute vec2 in_TexCoords;
attribute vec4 in_Color;

uniform mat3 matrixProjView;

varying vec4 var_Color;
varying vec2 var_TexCoords;

void main() {
  var_Color = in_Color;
  var_TexCoords = in_TexCoords;

  vec3 matr = matrixProjView * vec3(in_Position, 1.0);
  gl_Position = vec4(matr.xy, 0, matr.z);
}
```

Já o FragmentShader usado é:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
#define LOWP lowp
precision mediump float;
#else
#define LOWP
#endif

varying vec4 var_Color;
varying vec2 var_TexCoords;

uniform sampler2D uf_Texture;

void main (void) {
  gl_FragColor = var_Color * texture2D(uf_Texture, var_TexCoords);
}
```

O código fonte está no [GitHub](https://github.com/EngoEngine/engo/blob/master/common/render_shaders.go), caso seja necessário. Obviamente, as modificações que fiz, e mencionei acima, não estão por lá.

---

Estou há alguns dias procurando uma solução para o problema, mencionei aqui algumas tentativas que mais chegaram perto de dar algum resultado.

Queria saber o pode causar este problema e como poderia corrigi-lo, se é um problema com o OpenGL ou se pode até ser um problema no arrendondamento na hora de calcular a posição, por exemplo.

Apesar do código estar em Golang ele usa a mesma API em C, via CGO, e estou usando o OpenGL 4.6

Answer (score 0):

> Não sei se isto deveria de ser uma resposta, ou uma edição à pergunta.

---

Dentre várias tentativas de resolver o problema, o problema foi realmente mitigado usando "potencia de 2", se é que isso faz algum sentido dizer assim.

---

## Texturas

As texturas eram 100x100, entretanto o OpenGL, pelo que eu vi, apenas armazena as texturas em "potencia de 2", isso é: 32x32, 64x64, 128x128. Dessa forma a textura seria salva em 128x128, independente do valor inicial ser 100x100.

Isso já tinha sido modificado no momento que fiz a pergunta. Mas, isso não resolveu  o problema, não sozinho.

## Zoom ("eixo Z")

O zoom era acrescido a cada 0.125, ou seja o padrão seria de 1. O primeiro nível de zoom era 1.125 e depois 1.25, depois 1.375... O problema disso é que as texturas tinham que ser redimensionadas (seja expandindo ou encolhido), o `TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` é realmente o responsável por encolher a imagem e ele agora usa ainda o `NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST`.

Então, combinando com a mudança anterior (das texturas), fazer o zoom ser também em "potencia de 2" resolveu o problema. Dessa forma o zoom pode ser de: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, isto resolveu texturas sumirem. Mesmo em valores mais altos, como extremamente longe a textura ainda é visível em sua cor original.

## O X/Y

O eixo X/Y também é problemático e ainda não achei uma solução exata. Se estiver num ponto {X: 1, Y: 1} tudo ficará perfeito, independente do zoom (desde que um dos valores mencionados anteriormente). Mas, isso não funciona se estiver na coordenada {X: 6, Y: 6}, por alguma razão a coisa não funciona, algumas linhas ficam menores do que outras.

Estou ainda caçando uma solução melhor.

Já a rotação da câmera também foi travada para cada 45º graus, ao invés de pequenas etapas de 0.1. Isso também fez com que as linhas não caíssem num limbo e sumissem.

---

Enfim, isso mitigou o problema. O tamanho das texturas e os níveis de zoom e rotação resolveram o problema, de maneira geral. Há ainda algum caso exótico que causa o mesmo problema, mas é raro e estou investigando.